# Why are pressure/potential differences across a barrier measured from inside to outside?

Tags: electrostatics, solid-state-physics, medical-physics

I don't know if I'm asking clearly, but I'm a Medical Student who is trying to intuitively understand pressure differences and electrochemical gradient (across a semipermeable membrane) differences.

I've seen equations for either of these written as $\Delta P$ = (Pressure inside - Pressure outside) or Potential in $\Delta E$ = (milliVolts inside - milliVolts outside).

I know relativity is involved, but what does it mean when we're subtracting outside from inside? Is it saying that we have positive or negative pressure relative to the pressure on the inside? That'd be my best guess, but if someone could clarify, I'd be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: It should make no difference. I can't speak for the reasons in biophysics or biochemestry, but there are no physical differences. As long as you are consequent with your definition (negative or positive meaning inwards or outwards flow) there are no changes in the laws governing processes: the zone with higher pressure/potential will experience migration towards the zones with lower values.

Comment: But if I have a balloon with 5 atm inside and 1 atm outside, I'll get 5 atm - 1 atm = 4 atm or 1 atm - 5 atm = -4 atm.

This is fine with just numbers, but the answer below that described system vs. surroundings summed up which way things are supposed to be going pretty well.

Your answer makes sense, but if I subtract surroundings from system, my answer is "Relative to the system" so I know what is functionally being described when I say "negative" or "positive"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a conventions issue. When you define a system (a cell, a car tire, an atom), there is the system, and its surroundings. If you're interested in describing the **system**, you will discuss the properties of the system relative to the surroundings. Saying any given description of the system is positive is saying that the system has higher pressure / greater temperature / more potassium / higher electrostatic potential than the surroundings.

Mathematically, that works out to the above, P = inside - outside.